How to export Rhino blocks to Autodesk Viewer as a single geometry
I'm developing an app using Autodesk Viewer, and I've encountered a challenge with models from the design team that contain Rhino blocks. By default, the Viewer breaks down block geometry into individual pieces, making each piece clickable. While this behavior is acceptable for some views, I need to preserve blocks as single, solid geometries in others.
Interestingly, the Viewer correctly parses the model structure, and I can see and select block definitions in the model browser. However, during direct geometry selection, I'm only able to select individual meshes.
Is there a way to programmatically control the translation process to preserve blocks as single geometries? Currently, we use Rhino Inside to convert blocks to solid direct shapes via Revit, but this adds complexity to our workflow. Any suggestions for a more straightforward solution would be greatly appreciated.
Here T.A. is the block that i would like to select all at once clicking on any geometry belonging to it. Instead, each part gets selected separately

You might benefit from doing a selection override in order to achieve this. I don't think there is a way from the translation to change that. Check this and let us know how it goes - https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/selection-override
